# How to find largest multiple of m less than N only using bitwise operators?

Tags: bitwise-operators

I have a microcontroller project.I need to find the largest multiple of a number 'm' less than 'N' only using bitwise operators.

In my application, m is 12 & N= 4096. I am trying to avoid multiplication & division operations as it consumes time in the case of embedded application.

Comment: Is N a constant (i.e. known statically)?

Comment: @melpomene  Yes, In my case N is 4096. But 'm' will vary.